# How to create a rich text editor in Flutter like CKEditor or TinyMCE in JavaScript?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to create a rich text editor in Flutter like **[CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/)** or **[TinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/)** in JavaScript  **without an external package**?

I tried all the known packages for this in pub.dev.
Some of these packages:

- [rich_text_controller](https://pub.dev/packages/rich_text_controller)
- [easy_rich_text](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_rich_text)
- [flutter_markdown](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown)
- [flutter_quill](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill)
- [zefyrka](https://pub.dev/packages/zefyrka)
- And a relatively large number of other packages...

**Each of the available packages has problems. Some of these problems are:**

- Not supporting RTL
- Not compatible with all platforms
- Does not support attaching media or files

Also I tried to fix the incompatibilities by customizing the [zefyrka](https://pub.dev/packages/zefyrka) package but to no avail as it basically doesn't cover things like attaching media or RTL.

**So please guide me how to write the code of a Rich Text Editor from scratch without using the mentioned packages?**

Answer (score 0):

Add html_editor_enhanced: ^2.5.0 as dependency to your pubspec.yaml.

than you can use this code:

```
import 'package:html_editor/html_editor.dart';

HtmlEditorController controller = HtmlEditorController();

@override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return HtmlEditor(
        controller: controller, //required
        htmlEditorOptions: HtmlEditorOptions(
          hint: "Your text here...",
          //initalText: "text content initial, if any",
        ),   
        otherOptions: OtherOptions(
          height: 400,
        ),
    );
}
```

You can look this page: [package](https://pub.dev/packages/html_editor_enhanced)

Comment: I had already tried this package and it has the same problems as I said above. It means that it does not support Windows and it is not possible to attach a file to a document.

Comment: supports attach to document @Amin

Comment: Does not support Windows. Windows and Android are my two main platforms.